# Elasticsearch Gateway timeout 504

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I updated some indices mapping to simply add a `keyword` field to a text property and reloaded Kibana's index patterns. I was told I should run this command at the end:

```
POST 11ad.pi.prod.test-case-18/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed
```

after doing it I get an error:

```
{
"statusCode": 504,
"error": "Gateway Time-out",
"message": "Client request timeout"
}
```

does it mean the timeout is too short? how can it be changed?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's normal if your index has a substantial size. You don't need to see any timeout, the task is still ongoing in the background.

You can check the status of the update by query task by running `GET _tasks?actions=*byquery&detailed`.

Comment: offical document update for es 7.3, it says using "GET _tasks?detailed=true&actions=*/delete/byquery
" to check _delete_by_query tasks, check https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/docs-delete-by-query.html

Answer (score 2):

change the kibana.yml.
add the line:

```
elasticsearch.requestTimeout: 90000  # default 30s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to update the TransportClient's connection time out value:

```
Settings.builder().put("transport.tcp.connect_timeout", "240s")
```

The Complete TransportClient code:

```
Settings settings = Settings.builder()
        .put(ElasticSearchReservedWords.CLUSTER_NAME.getText(), LogHandlerConstants.CLUSTER_NAME)
        .put(ElasticSearchReservedWords.LISTENER_TRANSPORT_SNIFF.getText(), true)
        .put("transport.tcp.connect_timeout", "240s")
        .build();

Client transportClient = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
        .addTransportAddresses(
                new TransportAddress("127.0.0.1"), "9300"));
```

Each Elasticsearch version has different config key. You can read this document to learn about other settings you can change:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/modules-transport.html